# How do I extend cwise binary operations (or functions) in eigen

Tags: eigen

In eigen there are component-wise binary operators, like +,- etc. The are also two class functions cwiseMin and cwiseMax, but I would like to extend it with, at least, AbsDiff |xi - yi| ans SqrDiff (xi - yi)^2. But how to do it?

The only thing I could think of is to retrieve the two data pointers and operate on them (maybe, using cilk), but looks like a hack to me. I was expecting the possibility to define scalar functions like AbsDiff(x,y)=|x-y| ans SqrDiff(x,y)=(x-y)^2 and pass them to a generic eigen traversal routine, but apparently there is'nt. am I missing something, maybe simpler?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with writing `(x-y).cwiseAbs()` or `(x-y).cwiseAbs2()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
result = x.binaryExpr(y, func);
```

where `func` is a binary functor. But as I wrote above, for your use case it should be better to simply write

```
absdiff = (x-y).cwiseAbs();
sqrdiff = (x-y).cwiseAbs2();
```

These expressions will be evaluated lazily and will benefit from vectorization (if available).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, both of them. About binaryExpr,  I know that in the case of unaryExpr it is possible to pass even a std library function, for example double(double) (say, exp or sin), of course for an array of doubles, just passing the right signature. Do you think the same is possible for a function double(double,double) ?

Comment: If you have a function, `double f(double, double)`, just passing `std::ptr_fun(f)` as the functor should work.

Comment: As a side note, you can also pass C++ lambda to both unaryExpr and binaryExpr.